# How to recover my plugins data from plugin-registration in crm?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

When updating an assembly to plugin registration - in **step 2 : select the plugin and workflow activities to register**, if not all plugin selected they will be deleted with their steps and images from plugin registration, is there a way to recover a plugin that was deleted, is there an XML or a file that helps recover the steps and images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have earlier solution backup or take the latest solution by including the Sdk message Processing Steps from other environments & import to get the lost Plugin steps/images registration data.

[image]

Also, as an Ops guide for troubleshooting & human readable version tracker in TFS source code, I follow this on each plugin. This helped me a lot. Even if its not deployed correctly in other environments, this will help to identify the gap.

Helpful in some situation too (for future), if there is no other environments other than Dev yet.

[image]

Comment: ok so I need to import a solution with all my SDK MSGS  steps to my new environment and after publishing it plugin reg will load all steps and Images with my chosen attributes?

Comment: I'm checking the list of my Sdk message Processing steps and I can't figure where are the Images, how can I find them?

Comment: @Damkulul Images are part of Steps..It will come automatically