# Multiple projects into single dll

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm, crm, ilmerge

**Problem:**
We used CRM Plugin Registration Tool to update an assembly which was working fine before. We then started to get

```
Could not load file or assembly "Project 1 version ....Culture.. PublicKeyToken..."
```

**Details:** The assembly project referencing another project in the same solution:

- **Project 1** (Class Library - Will be the missing file or assembly in the above message)
- **Project 2** (Assembly want to deploy) : Referencing **Project 1**

After digging into the problem that was causing that error by comparing a working assembly with the new assembly that was throwing the error (Using dotPeek tool to view the dlls content) we found the difference in how **Project 1** existed in both assemblies.

- Working Assembly: **Project 1** **source code existed** in the assembly as a
  namespace (no dll) (Done by old developer who left)
- Bad/Error Assembly: **Project 1** existed as a **reference (dll file)**.

**Q:** How can I achieve the same behavior in my code/VS as the Working Assembly?

**If this help:** 
We use Dynamics CRM 2016 On-Premise, ILMerge, Visual Studio 2015

**Note:**

- We can't change from Database to Disk or GAC as tons of plugins and steps there
- We deploy assemblies into CRM in: Non-Sandbox & Database

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the old developer stuff. What you are doing is perfect. This is my recommendation.

**Forget about the old developer stuff.**

In Plugin registration tool, unregister that old assembly (where single dll is having both Project 1 & 2 under single namespace)

**What you are doing is perfect.**

Do an *Add reference* of Project 1 dll in Project 2.
Do ILMERGE & register this new assembly in PRT.
No need to change anything else.

You may have to [follow my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890181/7920473) for a trick shot to avoid re-registering steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ILMERGE to merge the different dlls you need into one and deploy that assembly into CRM.

We normally setup a post build event powershell script that merges all dlls into one directly after they are built.