# Plugin Registration Tool delete my steps on update revision number

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is this normal?
On dynamics, when I change the revision number of my plugin, and update it on the Plugin Registration Tool, it deletes my steps.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, when you forget to select/check all the plugins/steps to register whenever you are updating the assembly.

[image]

[You have to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890181/7920473): either manually register or take the solution from other environment & import here.

Comment: I believe this is actually a bug, or a change in behavior. We are seeing now, when uploading a new version of an assembly, that the current registered steps are not available to select, and are removed when updating the plugin

Comment: @BenWilliams pls ask a new question with screenshots to assist.

Comment: @BenWilliams I am seeing the same issue. Everytime I update an assembly all the steps are deleted, they are no longer selectable through the UI